# xsl:value-of removes HTML tags in XML data

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I create xml that includes html tags as you see below. I try to convert all the xml data to html according to my xslt. But, I can't handle html tags that included in xml. I need to get whatever in **summary** tag as it is written (without losing html tags). What should I do ?

```
<checklist name="00.07-Parts">
<summary>
  <table border="1" cellpadding="7" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <p><strong> aaaaaaa </strong></p>
        </td>
        <td>
        <p><strong> bbbbbbbb </strong></p>
        </td>
    </tr>           
  </tbody>
  </table>
</summary>
</checklist>
```

Here, my XSLT part

```
<xsl:for-each select="checklist">
          <table class="tbChecklist">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <h4>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                  </h4>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="summary"/>                                   
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Here the result

```
  <table class="tbChecklist">
  <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
             <h4>00.07-Parts</h4>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>
            aaaaaaa
            bbbbbbbb
      <td>
      <tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Try putting the HTML in a CDATA block.

Comment: Is the result the expected one or the current wrong one?

Comment: I put the result, not expected.

Comment: I need to get all the text in summary tag as written      <table border="1" cellpadding="7" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <p><strong> aaaaaaa </strong></p>
        </td>
        <td>
        <p><strong> bbbbbbbb </strong></p>
        </td>
    </tr>           
  </tbody>
  </table>

Answer (score 5):

you can simply use copy-of instead of value-of.
copy-of gives you the whole content of the selected node, including other nodes.

```
<xsl:copy-of select="summary"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need to get what ever in summary tag as it is written (without losing html tags).

Just use `xsl:copy-of select=" "` like this:

```
<xsl:template match="Customers/checklist">
  <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

Or, as mentioned above in the comments, with the HTML put in CDATA sections(which would only be useful if it is output as XML):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="checklist" />
  <xsl:template match="Customers/checklist">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which gives the following result output as XML:

```
<checklist name="00.07-Parts"><![CDATA[
]]><summary>
  <table border="1" cellpadding="7" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <p><strong> aaaaaaa </strong></p>
        </td>
        <td>
        <p><strong> bbbbbbbb </strong></p>
        </td>
    </tr>           
  </tbody>
  </table>
</summary><![CDATA[
]]></checklist>
```

Or, as a third way, to just copy all non-empty text() subnodes of summary-tag:

```
<xsl:template match="Customers/checklist">
    <xsl:copy-of select="descendant::text()[normalize-space(.) != '']" />
</xsl:template>
```